# Flutter showTimePicker always returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to use the showTimePicker function from flutter but what happens is the dialog shows up with the time picker, but once I tap on anything in the dialog it closes up and returns null. Even if I tap on a number in the picker.

I've tested this only on iOS.

I've tried wrapping up the InkWell in a Builder and giving the showTimePicker function the context from that builder but I get the same result.

I thought that maybe the InkWell was capturing the tap event from the dialog but I've set up a breakpoint in my _pickNewDailyResetTime method and it only comes in at the correct time, not when I tap in the dialog.

I have a single navigator set up for my bottom menu in parent widgets, if that's important.

Anyway here's my widget code, any help is appreciated :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class DailyResetTime extends StatefulWidget {
  DailyResetTime();

  @override
  _DailyResetTimeState createState() => _DailyResetTimeState();
}

class _DailyResetTimeState extends State<DailyResetTime> {
  TimeOfDay _dailyResetTime;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadDailyResetTime();
  }

  _loadDailyResetTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      String sDailyResetTime = prefs.getString('dailyResetTime');

      _dailyResetTime = sDailyResetTime != null
          ? TimeOfDay(
              hour: int.parse(sDailyResetTime.split(":")[0]),
              minute: int.parse(sDailyResetTime.split(":")[1]))
          : TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
    });
  }

  _pickNewDailyResetTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: _dailyResetTime)
        .then((value) {
      if (value == null) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {
        _dailyResetTime = value;
        prefs.setString('dailyResetTime',
            value.hour.toString() + ":" + value.minute.toString());
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: _pickNewDailyResetTime,
        child: Container(
            height: 48.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 1.0))),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text('Daily reset time'),
                Spacer(),
                Text(_dailyResetTime?.format(context) ?? '')
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the navigator was the issue, passing useRootNavigator: false to function parameter fixed the issue for me.